# LTS requirements?

Tags: developer, system

4.6.x is the LTS version, right? Previously, before the documentation was "upgraded" I could switch to previous versions and see what their system requirements were. Now I only see "latest", which I guess would mean the 4.7.x version, right? So the only ways to find the LTS requirements are?:

- Use Web GUI install and a zero configured test server to discover all that can be missing.
- still use drush civicrm-install trial an error
- "Just" scan through the code (it's open source after all)

My task is scriptable automatical installation with composer. I don't see any of the options really attractive. If LTS is serious, please restore the essential documentation for at least that version, if you have the time for it.

Comment: Currently the LTS needs php 5.3 - 5.6 ....but 5.3 support will likely be dropped beginning of next year "officially", that is we won't test it on that version.  Currently the LTS does not work on PHP7 but that is something that is being discussed for development next year.

Comment: MySQL, use 5.6, it is possible to get it to work with MySQL 5.7, but you must follow the instructions here: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18439

Comment: What is needed is a page with all requirements, since it is LTS. Long Term means that that there must be at least some documentation for that version. The very least in imho is the system requirements. I don't mind other documentation formats, but it must be something version specific available when requirements for LTS are different. You cannot expect a serious user to do trial an error. That is not my idea of what support means.

Comment: You are welcome to fund it sir!

Comment: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC46/CiviCRM+PHP+Requirements

Comment: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC46/Installation+and+Upgrades

Comment: Googling for 30 seconds got me those links above. The development of CiviCRM, and any associated resources, is done via donations, orgs sponsoring work, or people donating their time. Its free to you, but not to the people that spend their time. If you approach somebody who gives their free time in a negative, demanding tone, then you can expect some hurt feelings and some defensiveness. It did take me a little bit to learn this lesson. Instead join us and get involved yourself. chat.civicrm.org is a good place to start. Documentation channel. Ask how you can help.

Comment: You presuppose that I don't donate time and that I do not contribute. This very post is also a contribution to a better documentation. It is sad that you don't interpret it that way!

Comment: BTW in written language there is no tone, especially because I am not a novelist. I am glad to discuss it with you in audio chat, then you can hear my tone. I was just wondering what LTS means when there was no documentation for it in the main location where it  appeared before.

Comment: It's on our list of todos now. Feel free to contribute to the effort.

Answer (score 3):

A few comments:

- We're pretty happy with our Upgraded documentation - it's much more
  readable/much better organized - we thank Sean for having put countless of hours into that.
- CiviCRM 4.6.x is supported (for free) by Skvare and CompuCorp; they are pretty
  serious and we probably don't thank them enough for taking that on;

If you have specific questions - just ask (nicely) - and you'll find help here on SE. You will actually find that there is not too much difference in requirements between 4.7.x and 4.6.x - we run them side by side on the same server;

Comment: The documentation people didn't really consult with the LTS people either about the switch over, they kind of "just did it"

Comment: @jackrabbithanna there is a public discussion about documentation process at chat.civicrm.org - you are welcome to join in if you want to have input.

Comment: I didn't mean to sound negative...its more like progress marches on and contributor resources and priority for the migration of 4.6 documentation to the improved system has been low...I didn't realize until this post the 4.6 docs weren't there, and that any documentation migration didn't include it.